# How to prevent Android from inserting the trailing \n\n when SetText using Html.FromHtml()?

Tags: java, android

I setText for an EditText this way:

```
editText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p><a href='#'>Cadbury</a> is my fav chocolate</p>");
```

problem is, this line inserts two additional breakpoints on the EditText

when i get the value using `Html.toHtml(editText.getText())` the result is:

```
"<p><a href='#'>Cadbury</a> is my fav chocolate</p>\n\n"
```

I dont want the trailing \n's, how do i remove them?

Comment: `Html.fromHtml(text.replace("\n", "")` doesn't work either...

Comment: no, the problem is during SetText, android adds \n at the end, it creates an additional empty line in EditText

Comment: I guess this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16745540/1735100) is actually what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extra padding on TextView with HTML contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585557/extra-padding-on-textview-with-html-contents)

Comment: thanks a lot, fixed it :))