# Extra line breaks at end of text

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I seem to be getting what seems like some extra line breaks after using this method to set the text of a `TextView`

```
message.setText(Html.fromHtml( message ));
```

How can I remove these? They cause my layout to get warped since it adds two extra lines to the output.

The string was saved to my sqlite database via `Html.toHtml( editText.getText() ).trim();`

Initial string input : `hello`

Log output of the message variable: `<p dir="ltr">hello</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like toHtml assumes everything should be in a `<p>` tag.  I'd strip off the beginning and ending `<p>` and `</p>` tags before writing to the database.

Comment: beginning and ending what? I also use trim before storing

Comment: Sorry, formatting ate my code.  The paragraph tag.  Trim won't do that, it trims whitespace, not html tags.

Comment: hmm, how could I remove those tags specifically and leave the others intact

Comment: Ended up using a replace funtion on the string to remove the `<p>` tags as suggested seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this lines ... totally works ;)

i know your problem solved but maybe some one find this useful .

```
 try{
        string= replceLast(string,"<p dir=\"ltr\">", "");
        string=replceLast(string,"</p>", "");
}catch (Exception e) {}
```

and here is replaceLast ...

```
public String replceLast(String yourString, String frist,String second)
{
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(yourString);
    b.replace(yourString.lastIndexOf(frist), yourString.lastIndexOf(frist)+frist.length(),second );
    return b.toString();
}
```

Comment: nice try @Hamid Qasemy

Answer (score 3):

For kotlin you can use

```
html.trim('\n')
```

Comment: This is working fine with my code

Answer (score 2):

This is working as below in `Kotlin`.

```
val myHtmlString = "<p>Test<\/p>"

HtmlCompat.fromHtml(myHtmlString.trim(), FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT).trim('\n')
```