# Two extra lines added to edit text when retrieving html String

Tags: java, android, html, sqlite

I save my formatted edit text in sqlite database in html then after retrieving it two extra lines are added to the edit text

So I started like so:-

```
 edt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+myString+"</b>"));//making it bold
 Editable e = edt.getText();//convert to Editable
 String text = Html.toHtml(e);//convert to String
```

Then after I inserted **text** into the database .I retrieved it back to **edt** this way:-

```
Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(text);//convert text to spanned
edt.setText(sp);//setting to the edittext
```

It was retrieved successfully however 2 extra lines where added to **edt** at the end of text each time why you think that occurs?.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
edt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+myString+"</b>"));//making it bold
Editable e = edt.getText();//convert to Editable
/* String text = Html.toHtml(e);//convert to String

Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(text);  //convert text to spanned */
edt.setText(e);//setting to the edittext
```

Comment: this problem is Html.toHtml() and Html.fromHtml() adding escape word "\n".

Comment: Do you mean edt should be set from Editable instead of spanned ? this is the only difference I see from my code

Comment: I think It maybe the html extra line breaks

Comment: in Html.java you can find  withinDiv(StringBuilder out, Spanned text, int start, int end,
            int option){ ........ out.append("</blockquote>\n"); ....}

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution using code from an answer in this question [Remove extra line breaks after Html.fromHtml()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589381/remove-extra-line-breaks-after-html-fromhtml/9974562#9974562)
 .Its all about removing extra html whitspaces but using it for spannable 
  String like so :-

```
Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(subnote);

int h = sp.length();

// loop back to the first non-whitespace character

while(--h >= 0 && Character.isWhitespace(sp.charAt(h))) {
}

sp= (Spanned) sp.subSequence(0, h+1);



edt.setText(sp);
```